# 表情の同期をPhotonを使ってさせたい

Tags: c#, unity3d

Photonを使ってマルチプレイヤーのプロジェクトを作っております。
自分のアバターでSkin Mesh RendererのBlendshapesを実行後に変更したりしているのですが、
これをリアルタイムで他のプレイヤーにも自分のアバターのBlendshapesのパラメータを同期させるにはどのようにする方法がありますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

Photon のコンポーネントである Photon Animator View ではレイヤーのウェイトと Animator Controller のパラメーターのみ同期できます。

コンポーネントで同期できないものを同期させたい場合は PunRPC を使う必要があります。

- [UnityでPUNを使ったオンラインマルチプレイの実装 -PunRPC編-](https://tech.pjin.jp/blog/2016/09/25/unity_pun_5/)

Comment: ありがとうございます！PunRPCを使ったらうまくいきました！